# Override the empty() method for an abstract class in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

I've come across this problem many times, and I was hoping to solve it finally.

### Context

When creating a heterogeneous class hierarchy in MATLAB, there is a protected static method called `getDefaultScalarElement`, which allows you to define the default scalar object for creating arrays. If an element of the hierarchy is abstract, you can override that method to use a different class.

For example

```
classdef (Abstract) AbstractRoot < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous

    methods (Static, Access = protected)
        function DefaultObj = getDefaultScalarElement()
            DefaultObj = ConcreteSubclass1();
        end
    end

end

classdef ConcreteSubclass1 < AbstractRoot

end

classdef ConcreteSubclass2 < AbstractRoot

end
```

Every concrete class in matlab has a public static hidden method called `empty`, which creates an empty array of that object. I would like to create an empty method for the abstract class which is similar in functionality to the `getDefaultScalarObject` method. This would allow me to call `AbstractRoot.empty()` and receive an empty array of the default kind.

For example:

```
classdef (Abstract) AbstractRoot < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous

    methods (Static, Hidden)
        function EmptyObj = empty()
            EmptyObj = ConcreteSubclass1.empty();
        end
    end

    methods (Static, Access = protected)
        function DefaultObj = getDefaultScalarElement()
            DefaultObj = ConcreteSubclass1();
        end
    end

end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work (infinite recursion). The  main problem I have is that I'm not sure how to override `empty`, and still be able to call the built-in version of it from the subclass, since `empty` is not inherited from anywhere

### Questions

1. Is it possible to call the built-in version of empty? If so, how?
2. Is there a way of overriding empty in the abstract base class, so that subclasses will still call the built-in version of empty. Similarly, can I check which version of the static method was called (eg. 'AbstractRoot.empty' or 'ConcreteSubclass1.empty') from inside the method, so I can handle it on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never...

Its completely undocumented as far as I can tell: (can only verify for 2013a)

- Indexing a 1x1 array of any class
- with an empty double array of any possible size (0 in at least 1 dimension)
- will create a empty array the given class with the given size.

With this we can recreate an equivalent of the builtin version of empty for any class.

This can then be used to override the builtin version. Thus it can be defined, separately, for the subclasses, which will prevent the defined superclass method being called (and avoid the recursion).

So with 3 classdef m-files 
Firstly the second AbstractRoot definition from the question;
Then two subclasses having the `empty` method defined as below (with the `Obj` variable created as the required class)

```
classdef ConcreteSubclass1 < AbstractRoot 

    methods (Static, Hidden)
        function EmptyObj = empty( varargin )
            if isempty( varargin )   
                ind = double.empty;  %// as calling double.empty([]) errors
            else
                ind = double.empty( [varargin{:}] );  
            end
            Obj = ConcreteSubclass1();  %// or Obj = ConcreteSubclass2();
            EmptyObj = Obj(ind);
        end
    end

end
```

we can now call all 3 class.empty methods

```
a = AbstractRoot.empty
b = ConcreteSubclass2.empty
c = ConcreteSubclass1.empty

a = 

  0x0 ConcreteSubclass1 array with no properties.


b = 

  0x0 ConcreteSubclass2 array with no properties.


c = 

  0x0 ConcreteSubclass1 array with no properties.
```

Finally if the `empty` definition is omitted from a subclass of AbstractRoot, the overloaded version for abstract root will be called resulting in a ConcreteSubclass1 array

```
 d = ConcreteSubclass3.empty

d = 

  0x0 ConcreteSubclass1 array with no properties.
```

Comment: I like this solution. The only flaw I can see is that it requires constructing a scalar object of the specified class, and could not be used in cases where a subclass required arguments, or where constructing the subclass was expensive. Overall a good solution, though. Thanks!

Comment: @hoogamaphone Agreed, although Matlab says: "If you create a class constructor, you should implement class constructors so that they can be called with no input arguments, in addition to whatever arguments are normally required ", from [Rules for Constructors](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html#brd2m9e-3), As for the expense If your writing the constructor with a nargin check it may be reduced slightly. Although its still not an ideal solution...